# Jersey 1.x with Glassfish 4

Tags: java, rest, jersey, glassfish

Is there a consistent way to deploy a web application to Glassfish 4 while providing and using Jersey 1.x? It seems I have been able to do it once every now and then, but I cannot consistently reproduce the deployment.

Notes:

1. we cannot migrate to jersey 2 at the moment.
2. we cannot go back to Glassfish 3.x because our Security Team has flagged it as a threat... They typically win those arguments.

From the web and even a few threads here I have managed to compile a list of "things to do" even though I cannot find an example of one trying to do this exact thing (surprisingly enough)

We use maven and deploy with Jersey 1.17 the Jersey jar files that actually make it into the war files are as follows:

```
jersey-servlet-1.17.1.jar
jersey-spring-1.17.1.jar
jersey-server-1.17.1.jar
jersey-apache-client-1.17.1.jar
jersey-multipart-1.17.1.jar
jersey-client-1.17.1.jar
jersey-json-1.17.1.jar
jersey-core-1.17.1.jar
jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar
```

when we install (via maven) I pass

```
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.overrideablejavaxpackages=javax.ws.rs,javax.ws.rs.core,javax.ws.rs.ext
```

to maven's install..

We also deploy with a `glassfish-web.xml` file where we set the class loader delegate flag to "false"

Typical Deployment Exceptions:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.
```

These were a few of the tricks I have gathered from my research, and they definitely help, but I still seem to be missing something.

If it manages to deploy we often get:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
...
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
```

Both of these suggest Glassfish is still trying to use JAX-RS 2.0

Maybe there are some jar files we can safely remove from the Glassfish installation that are getting in the way, maybe there is another step (or steps) I can utilizes when deploying our war files.

Just curious if anyone out there has had to do this or knows how.